# npm install command works fine as root user but throws error if command is executed as jenkins user

Tags: node.js, linux, jenkins, npm

I am trying to run `npm install` in my Linux centos machine as `jenkins` but it is failing with:

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/jenkins/workspace/'job name'/Scheduler/scheduler-component/node_modules/ "
```

But if I run `npm install` as `root` this works fine.

Why does this happen and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem related to the $PATH and Global / Local, npm expect it to be there and its not, run as root using the root $PATH so files exists, the npm

[This Tutorial explains it](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

> It means that when doing something like fs.lstat('/home/ubuntu/.npm/iconv-lite/0.2.11/package/encodings/table/gbk.js', ...), npm received ENOENT error. Which means the file was missing, but npm expected it to be there.

if not try to :

1. Ensure dependencies described correctly on package.json Just type
   npm    install and hit Enter.
2. Check issue still exists. and If issue
   not    resolved, continue these methods.
3. type npm cache clean and
   hit Enter  type sudo npm install -g npm and hit Enter.
4. Retry npm
   install and hit    Enter.

Comment: Hi Please provide ERR so i can help http://www.competa.com/blog/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/